# What's the best place to showcase my pixel art?

Tags: graphics, assets, sprites

I recently started learning spriting/pixel art to help propel my game development endeavors and I've gotten to the point where I'd like to start sharing it for comments, critiques and other feedback.

I've got a pretty good awareness of some art sites out there but none of them have really struck me as ideal so I'm looking for suggestions from you guys!

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer: I'm looking for a place that accepts uploads like Flickr or DeviantArt but is focused on pixel art. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to look at [Pixel Joint](http://www.pixeljoint.com/). Good place to showcase your pixel art and gather feedback from other artists. Not as crowded as Deviant Art, though.

Comment: I endorse this!

Comment: Pixel Joint looks like what I wanted, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

There are some really great indies over on tigsource.com ([art board](http://forums.tigsource.com/index.php?board=24.0)). I've seen a lot of those guys pump out some really cool pixel art. I'm sure you'll find a fair amount of people willing to give you advice. You might check out [gamedev.net](http://www.gamedev.net) as well. I know Mark Eugn does a LOT of epic pixel art ([gd.net journal](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/mod/journal/journal.asp?jn=398180)).

To showcase your work, http://carbonmade.com/ might be the way to go. You can break what you do down into categories so people can find their focus faster. The interface for the site is nice.

Comment: Cool, I'll definitely check out that stuff, thanks! I'm looking for more of a service like DeviantArt (but for pixel art) though that supports uploads; I'd like to host my stuff on the cloud instead of hosting it myself.

Answer (score 0):

The [Pixelation](http://www.wayofthepixel.net/pixelation/index.php) forum has lower traffic but, has always been a good place for honest critiques. [DeviantArt](http://www.deviantart.com/) isn't geared specifically towards pixel art but, it's a great place to showcase and interact with other artists.